# Can I dynamically change the store of the grid Ext JS

Tags: extjs

So I have the `grid` which obviously has some `store` and on `beforerender` event I want to change the store of the grid? Can I do that ? If yes, how ?

Comment: I don't understand you people. If you know the answer no matter how simple it is why don't you write it instead of just downvoting the question ? I mean what will I get from that ? I won't get no answer? I won't get nothing. come on people.

Comment: Its a legitimate question, +1 from me to restore the balance. Chris's answer below should do the trick.

Comment: I upvoted too, Extjs Documentation is confusing and ill-organized which makes newbs have a hard time finding anything.

Comment: Finally, people who can think straight. Thanks, Chris's solution worked as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `reconfigure` method should do this for you:

> `reconfigure ([store], [columns])`
>
> Reconfigures the grid with a new store/columns. Either the store or the columns can be omitted if you don't wish to change them.

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure